# send messages with only one socket at different times

Tags: java, sockets

I'm developing a simple chat application that has a server and a client. I wanna use only one socket object in run-time. Example(Java Client) :

```
class POClient
{
    Socket socket;
    BufferedWriter out;

    POClient()
    {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 4445);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream());
        out = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    }

    void SendMessage()
    {
        out.write("Hello");
        out.flush();//edit
        // On this line, I need to use out.close() but if I close it, also 
        // socket will be closed. I don't wanna this. I wanna use only one instance.
    }
}
```

C# Server :

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();  //if a connection exists, the server will accept it

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            try
            {
                string line = "";
                while (true)
                {

                    line = reader.ReadToEnd();




                }
            }
```

If I don't use out.close(), 'reader' is waiting until out.close()

Where am I failing?

Comment: from MSDN "For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided."

Comment: So which method I use for reader or which reader I should use?

Comment: "If more control is needed over how many characters are read from the stream, use the Read(Char[], Int32, Int32) method overload, which generally results in better performance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think closing the connection is required for `ReadToEnd`. You would have to use other method like `Read()`.
In that case you would have to create a simple protocol of your own with simplest of forms being:

> |Data-Len in 4 bytes|----Data-----|

Then you would know how much to read and then read it. You would not have to close the connection in that case.

Also make sure to consider endien issues (if there are any) when converting length to byte array and back.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StreamReader.ReadLine()` instead of `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`, and before `out.flush()` add `out.newLine()`. This should write each message in new line and read from stream by lines.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to flush your writer. Do it like this:

```cs
out.flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to call  `out.flush()`.

The point of a `BufferedWriter` is that it writes data to an in memory buffer, and only sends it to the actual socket when the buffer is full or `flush()` is called.  This is for performance reasons, for example it's much more efficient to make a bunch of calls to put small bits of data into the `BufferedWriter` and then make a single call to `send` on the socket to actually send it out on the network.  Note that it works when you call `out.close()` because the `close` method flushes the writer before closing the underlying stream.

Comment: It is still waiting when I use "out.flush()"

Comment: Yeah, I think @Ata's answer might do the trick.  ReadToEnd will wait until it reaches the actual end of the stream, which for a socket only happens when it's closed.